# difference between field and term query or match query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have just started working on spring data elastic search .
I am just using simple spring data api like :-
findByName(String)
but when i m going through spric doc , i m able to see , it will create internal query like this :-

```
  @Query("{"bool" : {"must" : {"field" : {"name" : "?0"}}}}")
```

Now my questin is that is this field query similiar like match  query or term query in elastic search ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that latest ElasticSearch versions don't support `field` queries. The alternative to deprecated `field` query is `query_string` query which takes Lucene-like query as an input.

The `match` query allows to use a common search (search by keywords) and I think it's what you are looking for.

Af for `term` query, it won't analyze your input string and won't split it into terms. It will just use it as a search term. It's faster than `match` query but it won't work well with raw input.